# Wordpress wp_remote_post passing an array argument

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm sending a request using wp_remote_post.. Im passing an array in one of the $args and in the body of my $response is returning wrong key and value..

Code:

```
$x = $_POST['x']; // 50
$y = $_POST['y']; // "sample"

if (isset($x)) {
  $args['x'] = array($x);
}

if (isset($y)) {
  $args['y'] = $y
}

$response = wp_remote_post($post_url, array(
  'method' => 'POST',
  'timeout' => 45,
  'redirection' => 5,
  'httpversion' => '1.0',
  'blocking' => true,
  'headers' => array(),
  'body' => $args,
  'cookies' => array()
 ));

echo json_encode($response);
```

The Json encode response:

```
"body": "{\"x[0]\":\"50\", \"y\":\"sample\"}"
```

My expected response:

```
"body": "{\"x\":[50], \"y\":\"sample\"}"
```

Comment: Thats because `wp_remote_post` returns an array so your response is in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.. I just need to put $args inside json_encode()..

```
'body' => json_encode($args)
```